# Recommended order for re-shingling a roof and rebuilding a chimney

Tags: roof, roofing, chimney

I just found out that I should replace my (currently asphalt shingle) roof in the next year. I also was told by a chimney cleaner that in order to use my fireplace, I would need to have the flue re-lined and the chimney rebuilt from the roof up. So I am wondering about recommended order of doing these two projects.

Also, is there any significant cost savings if I get the chimney rebuilt near the same time as replacing the roof?

Comment: Get a second opinion on the chimney work before you "rebuild" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely do the chimney project first. Any foot traffic on your roof reduces its life by damaging the surface. In the case of asphalt shingles, the granules are the primary weather and UV light protection. Walking on an asphalt roof always degrades the granule surface, especially at the bottom edge of each shingle. That takes years off their useful life.